# Consuming JSON data but it is showing as Array instead of Hash. Why?

Tags: json, ruby, api

```
def self.top
        data = JSON.parse(open("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd").read)
        i = 0
        while i < data.length
            puts "#{i +1}. #{data[i]["name"]}"
            i += 1
        end
        data.instance_of? Array
    end
end
```

I'm getting this weird issue. Its returning true for instance_of array and false for a hash when i check it? Am I misunderstanding something here?

Also, would I be able to somehow rewrite that while loop for as an enumerable using data.each or data.collect etc.? It's probably something really basic I'm missing here.

Here is the API I'm consuming: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd

```
[
  {
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "symbol": "btc",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "current_price": 9950.38,
    "market_cap": 182891806069,
    "market_cap_rank": 1,
    "total_volume": 56103214574,
    "high_24h": 10008.09,
    "low_24h": 9714.09,
    "price_change_24h": 151.47,
    "price_change_percentage_24h": 1.54578,
    "market_cap_change_24h": 3302266164,
    "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": 1.83879,
    "circulating_supply": 18369100.0,
    "total_supply": 21000000.0,
    "ath": 19665.39,
    "ath_change_percentage": -49.41389,
    "ath_date": "2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "atl": 67.81,
    "atl_change_percentage": 14570.55603,
    "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "roi": null,
    "last_updated": "2020-05-08T18:35:22.865Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "ethereum",
    "symbol": "eth",
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1547034048",
    "current_price": 214.11,
    "market_cap": 23772912780,
    "market_cap_rank": 2,
    "total_volume": 18611819582,
    "high_24h": 215.12,
    "low_24h": 207.21,
    "price_change_24h": 0.573439,
    "price_change_percentage_24h": 0.26855,
    "market_cap_change_24h": 169896199,
    "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": 0.71981,
    "circulating_supply": 110845051.624,
    "total_supply": null,
    "ath": 1448.18,
    "ath_change_percentage": -85.23081,
    "ath_date": "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "atl": 0.432979,
    "atl_change_percentage": 49298.3854,
    "atl_date": "2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "roi": {
      "times": 27.75112172597611,
      "currency": "btc",
      "percentage": 2775.112172597611
    },
    "last_updated": "2020-05-08T18:35:50.326Z"
  },
```

That IS a hash right? I'm not crazy?

Comment: It's not a hash. It's an array of hashes. Check the first character, it's `[` (array open bracket). And yeah, you can use `data.each` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: @maxpleaner ok so i will need a `data.each do |hash|` then inside that `hash.collect do |key,  value|`? That would be the right way right? Sorry, n00b here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Please edit your question and supply the _minimal_ JSON in the question that is necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan the json api is linked in the post twice?

Comment: Links don't meet the requirements. Extract the JSON, reduce it to the minimum that demonstrates the problem. Asking us to retrieve the data and analyze it adds to the work we do to help you, and many won't bother helping. We expect you to do that foot-work since you're asking for help. As the MCVE says "Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem _in the question itself_".

Comment: @theTinMan i think thats a bit of a stretch. but i've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to continue our discussion from the comments in this answer because I think it solves your question.

In terms of whether you need `collect` (or its more commonly used alias `map`), well that depends on what you need to do with this data.

To use the code you've given as a guide, then no, you don't need it in this case. You are just trying to loop over the array of hashes and print out the "name" property of each:

```
    data.each_with_index do |hsh, i|
      puts "#{i +1}. #{hsh["name"]}"
    end
```

If you wanted to print out *every* key-val of every hash as its own line, that would be a case where you can *iterate* over the hash. Whether you use `each` or `map`/`collect` depends on whether you need to assign the result to a variable. For example the following two snippets are functionally identical, however with `map` you are transforming the array into a new array (`each` is *only* used for side effects and the return value of the block is discarded):

1. Printing each key-val of each hash with `each`:

   ```
   data.each.with_index do |hsh, i|
     hsh.each do |key, val|
       puts "#{i + 1} #{key} = #{val}"
     end
   end
   ```
2. The same thing but using `map` to make a new, transformed array:

   ```
   data.each.with_index do |hsh, i|
     lines_to_print = hsh.map do |key, val|
       "#{i + 1} #{key} = #{val}"
     end
     lines_to_print.each { |line| puts line }
   end
   ```

I recommend reading more about `each`, `map`, and other Ruby Enumerable methods, I can't really give an in-depth explanation of everything here because the scope is a bit too large.  But hopefully this example is illustrative anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't even aware arrays were allowed to store hashes lol. I thought that a hash could only be inside of another hash, As for each and collect, im outputting data and it seems easier to organize it just using a while loop i think,

Comment: @nolyoi sure, although `each_with_index` is more idiomatic than the `while` loop and no more verbose either, so I would recommend that. And yeah, arrays and hashes can contain any data types, you can even have a hash as a key in a hash, how about that?

Comment: "I wasn't even aware arrays were allowed to store hashes lol" – There is no array police that "allows" them to store certain things and not others. Arrays store objects. Period.